# Reading kml file to get coordinates in c#

Tags: c#, xml, kml, gmap.net

Okay, so I've been working on reading in a kml file that contains the coordinates of the boundary of every county/city in America. However, I've ran into some problems. Particularly, how to get the value of the NextNode and what to do when there is another element tag in the middle of an element's value.

Here is what the kml file looks like:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="gadm36_USA_2" id="gadm36_USA_2">
    <SimpleField name="NAME_0" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NAME_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NAME_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>gadm36_USA_2</name>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gadm36_USA_2">
        <SimpleData name="NAME_0">United States</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME_1">Alabama</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME_2">Autauga</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-86.8189620971679,32.3402709960939 -86.8108367919922,32.3471298217775 -86.8097915649414,32.3535118103028 -86.8103485107422,32.3585205078126 -86.8158340454101,32.3703498840333 -86.8239974975586,32.3785285949708 -86.8310775756835,32.3839797973634 -86.83544921875,32.3912506103515 -86.8419876098633,32.3980712890626 -86.8452758789062,32.4044418334961 -86.8458633422851,32.4140090942383 -86.8447875976562,32.4167404174805 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-86.8426208496093,32.4181213378907 -86.8361129760742,32.4204101562501 -86.8296127319336,32.4227104187012 -86.8274383544922,32.4240798950195 -86.8263626098633,32.4259109497071 -86.8280029296875,32.4277305603028 -86.8307189941406,32.4295387268066 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
```

Note, this is not an actual example where these random element tags appear in the middle of the coordinates, the counties that have them typically have a massive coordinate list and from my experience if i go through the kml file and only use the values before the first element tags, it appears to map out the correct county boundaries

```cs
List<string> locationList = new List<string>();
var doc = XDocument.Load("gadm36_USA1.kml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
var result = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Placemark");
foreach (XElement xmlInfo in result)
{
   var region = xmlInfo.Element(ns + "ExtendedData").Element(ns + "SchemaData").Value;
   //var country = region.Element(ns + "SimpleData").Value;
   //var state = region.Element(ns + "SimpleData");
   //var cityCounty = region.Element(ns + "SimpleData");
   locationList = xmlInfo.Element(ns + "MultiGeometry").Value.Split(' ').ToList();
   CountyCoordinates.Add(region, locationList);
}
```

So when i get to the variable "region", it groups all the element values together. For example it will say "United StatesAutaugaAlabama".

As for the coordinates, since there are these random element tags in the middle of the coordinate values, when i split the coordinates by " ", it gets screwed up when it hits these random element tags. (when it gets to that text in the middle of the coordinates the split will return '-86, 32 -86', instead of just '-86, 32') So, I'm essentially looking for help on how to read in the country, state, and county separately and how to properly read in the coordinates despite these random element tags.

Comment: The xml is multi-level document with a lot of different layers.  You have to look for the tag that had the names before looking for the MultiGeometry.

Comment: The elements are never random.  The KML files are huge, contain many layers, and are machine generated.  The file may not make a lot of sense to you, but the computers that read the file can make sense of these files.  The KML files are meant to generate pictures that your brain can see, but the data may be fractured and your eyes do not care if everything is continuous.  I've worked with a lot of these KML files helping OP parse the data.  One time it took me a week to complete one of these tasks because I kept on getting out of memory errors.  You are lucky that your file it not huge..

Comment: I'm not following how to handle the multi layers. Can you guys give any more direction on how exactly to do that.  I've worked with parsing xml files, but kml files are very new to me

Comment: So instead of looking for the MultiGeometry, would i just look for coordinates?

Comment: If coordinates is the parent that gives you all the properties you need.  Right now you are only posted the Placemarks.  Place marks will give you both Name and Coordinates.  I would look for all the Placemarks  But Placemarks does not give you all the Towns on the Map.  Roads are one layer, Locations (like towns and cities) are another layer, and  Placemarks are another layer.  Which layer(s) do you need?

Comment: So I figured out how to get the coordinates correctly, now I need help getting the state and county separately

Comment: List<Xelements> extendedDatas = doc.Descendents("ExtendedData").ToList(); foreach(XElement extendedData.in extendedDatas){ List<XElement> simpleFields =  extendedData.Elements("SimpleField").ToList(); }

Comment: So I tried this out and simpleFields is null every loop in the foreach

Comment: The tag SimpleData is a child of ExtendedData, not SimpleField.

Comment: Even after modifying your code, i still get a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested with following a get results :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<XElement> simpleFields;

            List<XElement> extendedDatas = doc.Descendants(ns + "ExtendedData").ToList(); 

            foreach(XElement extendedData in extendedDatas)
            {
                simpleFields = extendedData.Descendants(ns + "SimpleData").ToList(); 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
     List<XElement> extendedDatas = doc.Descendants(ns + "ExtendedData").ToList();
            var a_docment = root.Element(ns + "Document").Value;
            var result = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Placemark");
            foreach (XElement xmlInfo in result)
            {
     
                List<string> locationList = new List<string>();
                var gg  = xmlInfo.Descendants(ns + "outerBoundaryIs").ToList();
    
                foreach (XElement extendedData in gg)
                {
                    locationList.AddRange(extendedData.Value.Split(' ').ToList());
                }
```